# Check value against array and return another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm building a click type game and I need to see if the answer the user selected is correct by comparing it to an array.

This is the JSON

```
    {
     quiztitle: "Select the States",
     correct_answers: "9",
     states: [
       {
        state_name: "Alabama",
        image: "alabama_image",
        answer: "correct"
       },

       {
        state_name: "Alberta",
        image: "alberta_image",
        answer: "incorrect"
       },
ect...
```

When a user clicks a button, it takes the value and needs to check if it's correct. What is the best way to do this.

This is my attempt so far:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.matchBtns', function(){
                    var value = $(this.innerHTML);
                    if($.inArray(value, data.states)){
                       //its in the array
                       }else{
                         //its not
                         }
            });
```

I'm unsure how to access the value 'answer' to check if correct or not

This is the html button

```
<button class="matchBtns">*State Name Here*</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bit of the way, but there's still a lot to do. First off, you don't want a jQuery object of the text inside the button; you just want the text. So you can do something like this:

```
var value = $(this).text();
```

Secondly. `$.inArray` won't work for two reasons. One - It's a multidimensional array of objects. Two - you don't just want to check if it's in the array; you want to check if it's in the array **and** has the correct property.

So, you could iterate over the array and see if any of the answers are correct:

```
$('body').on('click', '.matchBtns', function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var correct = false;

    $.each(data.states, function(i, state) {
        if ( state.state_name == value && state.answer == 'correct' ) {
            correct = true;
            return false; // break out of $.each()
        }
    });

    if ( correct ) {
        // true
    }
    else {
        // false
    }
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0gtqjcL/

You could simplify this by storing `answer` (or `correct`) as a boolean, not a string. That way, you could do something like this:

```
if ( state.state_name == value && state.correct )
```

Comment: This is currently returning all answers as wrong atm @christian varga

Comment: @Dale I was accidentally checking `state.correct` instead of `state.answer`. I've fixed this up (check my edited answer). Make sure you read over people's answers before copying them to see if you can spot issues like this - it's pretty easy to spot, and you don't want to get into a habit of just blindly copying answers hoping that they'll work. Quite often, you'll need to modify answers to suit your needs.

Comment: I was reading I promise! Just new at jquery & overly tired. I appreciate your help, this code is working now.

Comment: @Dale Haha sorry mate I was probably a bit rude there. It's easy for me to say that it's easy to spot when I've been doing it so long :p. Anyway, glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

if you like `underscore` you may try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.matchBtns', function(){
                    var value = $(this.innerHTML);
                    if(_.contains(_.pluck(data.states, "answer"), value)) {
                       //is in the array
                       }
                     else{
                         //is not
                      }
            });
```

`_.pluck(array, "x")` is a shorthand for `_.map(array, function(x){return x.x;)`, so that you won't try to compare string and object

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to loop through the answers.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.matchBtns', function(){
   ...
   var value = this.innerHTML;
   for (var i = 0,l = data.states.length; i< l; i++){
       if (data.states[i].state_name === value && data.states[i].answer === 'correct'){
           /// is correct
           break; // to stop the loop
       }else {
          // not correct, continue
       }
   }
   ...
}
```